# Class article with argument titlepage changes symbol of \thanks to arabic number - how to avoid?

Tags: titles, article

I have the problem that

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\title{A great title \thanks{XYZ}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

gives a footnote with symbol (*) which I want to have, but when giving

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
```

the * is changed to a 1. I want to have the title page with the star, not with the 1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution: Change the format of the footnote counter to be a star:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\title{A great title \thanks{XYZ}}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\thefootnote{*}
\maketitle
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```